# Difference between NSLayoutAttributeLeft vs NSLayoutAttributeLeading

Tags: ios, attributes, constraints, autolayout

What is the difference between `NSLayoutAttributeLeft` and `NSLayoutAttributeLeading` in iOS autolayouts?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

"Leading" does not always mean "Left". 
For RTL-written languages (locales) leading edge of the object’s alignment rectangle will be located at the right side of the object.

Quote from [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutConcepts/AutoLayoutConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH14-SW1):

> The attributes leading and trailing are the same as left and right for left-to-right languages such as English, but in a right-to-left environment such as Hebrew or Arabic, leading and trailing are the same as right and left. When you create constraints, leading and trailing are the default values. You should usually use leading and trailing to make sure your interface is laid out appropriately in all languages unless you’re making constraints that should remain the same regardless of language (such as the order of master and detail panes in a split view).

Comment: Can you share any related link, it could be more helpful

Comment: There's not much more to be said. This is the correct answer. Leading is always where the text begins from - in English, the left, in Arabic, the right.

Comment: This attribute not work in iOS 8 , I tested now NSLayoutAttributeLeading and NSLayoutAttributeTrailing still didn't reflect to another side

Comment: So in the 99% of cases when you're working with UIViews that are not representing any language, they're the same, eh :P