# Force UIImageView Alignment LTR in RTL Layout

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have an iOS Application which i has 2 languages Arabic/English  , Arabic language is an RTL Language so when i switch language to Arabic the app running with RTL Layout And that's working

I am just need to force an UIImageView to be LTR when the whole layout is RTL so i used this piece of code :

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var userImage:UIImageView! 


override func viewDidLoad()
{
super.viewDidLoad()

    self.userImage.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
}


}
```

but it's not working and the UIImageView Still in right position

any help how can i do that ?

> Here's a screenshot from my simulator i need to make the image in
>   NavigationController  in Left position

[image]

Comment: Is your imageView inside navigation controller?

Answer (score 1):

First open your storyboard in XML (Source code) then

Search for `leading` (in Constraints) and replace it with `left` and same

 Search for `trailing` (in Constraints) and replace it with `right`

second options is use semantic property

[image]

if you doing with label text  then here is my question

[Combine Two Language Text RTL & LTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848130/combine-two-language-text-rtl-ltr)

Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: I did the second opton from the storyboard but didn't work too

Comment: Can you explain the first option  ?

Comment: @Muhammed pls have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971508/difference-between-nslayoutattributeleft-vs-nslayoutattributeleading

Comment: Yea but i think that will change the whole layout not a specific view ?

Comment: @Muhammed Yes if you need for image then just change for imageview only

Comment: BTW your page has just mapview which should have any much effect with this change

Comment: yea but i will make this change in multiple view controllers

Comment: @Muhammed If you see  `<!--View Controller-->` in your xml file where you can identify your view controller there

Comment: <rect key="frame" x="20" y="14" width="35" height="35"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="35" id="gaw-br-o2j"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="35" id="hEq-tt-aJD"/>

Comment: this is my imageView constraints in storyboard as a source code

Comment: @Muhammed follow the steps 1) find imageview like  `<imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="in.png" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="oqr-sL-AZw">`  now if you see  `id="oqr-sL-AZw"`

Comment: @Muhammed step2) Now search that `"oqr-sL-AZw"` where you can  in constraint and change leading to left

Comment: didn't get it .

Comment: @Muhammed  I mean mark this question as accepted a green check mark sign beneath the down vote button. so it may be helpful to others as well :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If using auto layout constraints:

1- Double Trailing or Leading constraint of the view

2- Click "First Item" drop down menu

3- Uncheck "Respect language direction"

4- You might need to do step 2 and 3 for "Second Item" as well.

You need to do this for all views with Trailing and Leading constraints to replace them with right and left constraints.